# Finding the probability that a permutation of $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ leaves all odd numbers in odd-numbered positions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Suppose the numbers $1,2,3,4,5$ are arranged in a random order. Find the probability that all odd numbers still appear in odd-numbered positions.

I thought to solve it by listing what they want.

$1 \square 3 \square 5$

$1 \square 5 \square 3$

$3 \square 1 \square 5$

$3 \square 5 \square 1$

$5 \square 1 \square 3$

$5 \square 3 \square 1$

which is $6$ options from $5!$.  Is this correct?

Comment: There are more than six options.  Note: you haven't done anything about the even numbers yet.

Comment: As an aside, although brute force counting it by hand is sometimes an option for smaller problems and can provide insight, for larger problems it is far too tedious and prone to error.  You should come up with a *combinatorial* argument as to how many arrangements have the property you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is meant to be P(3,3)*P(2,2)=6*2=12.
On first,third and fifth place:6 choices;
On the second and forth place:2 choices;
So there are 12 choices you want.

P(5,5)=120.
There are 120 ways to arrange the number.

So the probability is 12/120=10%

Comment: "*Find the* **probability** *that*..."  You should keep going.  Also, it would help the OP more if you explain why you chose the numbers you did.

Comment: You are right. I edited it.

Comment: @abc... can you explain the P(3,3)*P(2,2) = 12  ? Sorry, I'm just trying to understand it.

Comment: Is that clearer?

Comment: I really advise you to learn combinations and permutations before probability.

Comment: @abc.. yes, thank you.